# FadeOut() function

Tags: jquery, html, image, fadein, fadeout

I have a simple question to you. Why below code doesn't work properly - images can't dissapear. What is wrong? I have to use fadeOut function in jQuery. Maybe it's a syntax error?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>FadeOut - jQuery</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#outercorners img {
    display:yes;
}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

var x=1; // The corner counter

function fading() {
  $("#corner"+(++x)).fadeOut(2000); // Fade in the current corner

  if (x==5) { // Last image to be faded in?
    clearInterval(); // Stop interval
  }
} 

$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
  setInterval("fading()",1000); // Call function every second
});

</script>



</head>

<body>

<button>Start!</button>

<div id="outercorners">

 <img id="corner1" src="images/mouse_1.jpg" width="200" height="150"/>
 <img id="corner2" src="images/mouse_2.jpg" width="200" height="150"/>
 <img id="corner3" src="images/mouse_3.jpg" width="200" height="150"/>
 <img id="corner4" src="images/mouse_4.jpg" width="200" height="150"/>


 <div id="corner5"><img src="images/mouse_5.jpg" width="200" height="150" />
  <img id="corner6" src="images/mouse_6.jpg" width="200" height="150"/>
 <img id="corner6" src="images/mouse_7.jpg" width="200" height="150"/>
 <img id="corner7" src="images/mouse_8.jpg" width="200" height="150"/>


 <div id="corner9"><img src="images/mouse_9.jpg" width="200" height="150" />
  <img id="corner10" src="images/mouse_10.jpg" width="200" height="150"/>
 <img id="corner11" src="images/mouse_11.jpg" width="200" height="150"/>
 <img id="corner12" src="images/mouse_12.jpg" width="200" height="150"/>

  <div id="corner13"><img src="images/mouse_13.jpg" width="200" height="150" />
  <img id="corner14" src="images/mouse_14.jpg" width="200" height="150"/>
 <img id="corner15" src="images/mouse_15.jpg" width="200" height="150"/>
 <img id="corner16" src="images/mouse_16.jpg" width="200" height="150"/>

 </div>





</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you forgot to close DOM ready, some other minor mistakes and you should consider upgrading the jQuery version.

Comment: You have 2 unclosed divs as well, guess they should be images.

Comment: Just so you know, you're using a very old version of jQuery, you should use 1.8.2

Answer (score 0):

First off, you forgot to close the DOM ready handler which generates a syntax error.

You also should store a reference to the interval to pass it to `clearInterval`.

Your increment logic was slightly off too. To fade in the first 4 corners it'd be:

```
var x = 0,
    interval;

function fading() {
    $("#corner" + (++x)).fadeOut(2000); // Fade in the current corner
    if (x == 4) { // Last image to be faded in
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        interval = setInterval(fading, 1000);
    });
}); //<-- you forgot to close DOM ready
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2j8TM/)

---

Also as commented, consider upgrading the jQuery version to a more up-to-date one. jQuery 1.8.3 is out already.

One more thing, your comments say "fade in" but you're calling `fadeOut`. If you want to fade in `display:none` elements, replace the `fadeOut` call by `fadeIn`.

Comment: I changed my code and it's works! But I have one more question. In my code occurs image (he is divided by 16 elements). Then I clicked "Start" button only the first line disappears - other lines can't fadeOut.

Comment: @user1869274 change the 4 in `x == 4` by 16. Note that in the code you pasted, you have some unclosed `div`s that apparently should be images, fix that too.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the latest jQuery libray, cleaned your HTML and fixed the javascript:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/igufen/1/edit)*

```
var x=1;  // The corner counter
var intv; 


function fading() {

  $("#corner"+(x++)).fadeOut(2000); // Fade in the current corner

  if (x%6===0) { // Last image to be faded in?
    clearInterval(intv); // Stop interval
  }
  
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    intv = setInterval(fading,1000); // Call function every second
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<button>Start!</button>

<div id="outercorners">

 <img id="corner1" src="images/mouse_1.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="1" />
 <img id="corner2" src="images/mouse_2.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="2" />
 <img id="corner3" src="images/mouse_3.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="3" />
 <img id="corner4" src="images/mouse_4.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="4" />

 
 <img id="corner5" src="images/mouse_5.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="5" />
 <img id="corner6" src="images/mouse_6.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="6" />
 <img id="corner6" src="images/mouse_7.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="7" />
 <img id="corner7" src="images/mouse_8.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="8" />
 
 
 <img id="corner9"  src="images/mouse_9.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="9" />
 <img id="corner10" src="images/mouse_10.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="10" />
 <img id="corner11" src="images/mouse_11.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="11" />
 <img id="corner12" src="images/mouse_12.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="12" />
 
 <img id="corner13" src="images/mouse_13.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="13" />
 <img id="corner14" src="images/mouse_14.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="14" />
 <img id="corner15" src="images/mouse_15.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="15" />
 <img id="corner16" src="images/mouse_16.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="16" />
 
</div>
```

`(x%6===0)` this Modulo will help you to fade 5 by 5 images at a time.